# Secure erase partition only on SSD, not the whole thing

Tags: encryption, linux, disk-encryption, ssd, partition

I have a 512 SSD which is partitioned into essentially two 256 areas. One for Windows, the other for Linux (Ubuntu). Neither is encrypted. I want to clean my system up, but am only concerned about the linux partition. I understand you can not securely delete files from ssd due to the firmware deciding where to put data.

My question is if the linux partition is wiped/formatted then encrypted with a reinstall, will that sufffice or will the old data be spread across partitions (wear-leveling)?

This may seem like a silly question, but my knowledge of this sort of thing is limited.

Answer (score 2):

Wear leveling is independent of partitions. All of your data is spread out over all of the flash chips in the SSD.

Comment: While generally true there are secure designs that erase returned blocks.

Comment: @zaph which would still be independent of partitions

Comment: So I read from that the whole disc would need to be dealt with